# How to obtain certain information from a specified format in c++?

Tags: c++

Beginner programmer here,
Say I want to obtain initial starting coordinates in the form (x,y), so I ask the user to enter in a point using the specific form "(x,y)". Is there a way that I could recognize the format and parse the string so that I could obtain the x and y values?

Answer (score 1):

Read a line of text using:

```
char line[200]; // Make it large enough.
int x;
int y;

fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
```

Then, use `sscanf` to read the numbers from the line of text.

```
if ( sscanf(line, "(%d,%d)", &x, &y) != 2 )
{
   // Deal with error.
}
else
{
   // Got the numbers.
   // Use them.
}
```

If you want to use iostreams instead of stdio, use `getline` instead of `fgets`.

Comment: @n.m., One could use C++ to read a line of text. I still think `sscanf` is the most straight forward way to extract the numbers given the format.

Comment: " I still think sscanf is the most straight forward way to extract the numbers given the format". I think you are very much mistaken.

Comment: @n.m., please feel free to edit my answer, or better still, post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the matching sequence anywhere in the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::getline(std::cin, line);

  std::regex e(R"R(\(([-+]?(?:\d*[.])?\d+)\s*,\s*([-+]?(?:\d*[.])?\d+)\))R");

  std::smatch sm;
  if (std::regex_search(line, sm, e)) {
    auto x = std::stod(sm[1]);
    auto y = std::stod(sm[2]);
    std::cout << "Numbers are: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `e(R"R(\(([-+]?(?:\d*[.])?\d+)\s*,\s*([-+]?(?:\d*[.])?\d+)\))R");` is the exact stuff you want to teach a new programmer, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

In order to *parse* stuff you need a *parser*. There are many ways to write a parser, but generally parsers read *tokens* and decide what to do next based on which token it is. (Emphasized words are important, look them up).

In your case you don't have to explicitly introduce a separate token entity. Reading elements from the input stream with the `>>` operator will do.

You need to:

- read a character; verify it's a `'('`
- read a number
- read a character; verify it's a `','`
- read a number
- read a character; verify it's a `')'`

If any step fails, the entire parsing fails.

You can see the same basic step is done three times, so you can write a function for it.

```
bool expect_char(std::istream& is, char what)
{
  char ch;
  return is >> ch && ch == what;
}
```

This works because `is >> ch` returns the stream after the read operation, and the stream can be viewed as a boolean value: `true` if the last operation succeeded, `false` otherwise.

Now you can compose your parser:

```
bool get_vector (std::istream& is, int& x, int& y)
{
   return expect_char(is, '(') &&
          is >> x              &&
          expect_char(is, ',') &&
          is >> y              &&
          expect_char(is, ')');
}
```

This method has a nice property that blanks are allowed between the numbers and the symbols.

Now this may look like a lot of stuff to type compared to the solution that uses `sscanf`:

```
bool get_numbers2 (std::istream& is, int& x, int& y)
{
   std::string s;
   return std::getline(in, s) &&
          (std::sscanf(s.c_str(), "(%d,%d)", &x, &y) == 2);
}
```

But `sscanf` is:

- dangerous (there is no typechecking of its arguments)
- less powerful (the input format is very rigid)
- not generic (doesn't work in a template)

It's OK to use the `scanf` functions family where appropriate, but I don't recommend it for new C++ programmers.